Does AWS Step-functions-local support map tasks?
I am trying to write automated tests using the AWS Step-Functions-Local service against a state machine that has a map task in it. I can create the state machine just fine with no errors in the step-functions-local container, but as soon as I try to execute one of the tests, I get an error message indicating that my state machine has syntax errors.
So, I created a state machine from scratch that had only a map task and a success step. Got the same error executing a test against it. Removed the map task and the test passed.
I know that the local version doesn't have full feature parity, but I have yet to find something that explains definitely what is / isn't there. I'm guessing the answer to my question is that map tasks are one of those missing features, but I want to make sure that I haven't done something wrong.

I think you were using ItemProcessor field, which is used to define processing steps within a Map State, which is not supported in Step Function Local. Instead you can use the Iterator field when defining Map states for local testing.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/state-map-inline.html
this is an example of the iterator:
{
  "Type": "Map",
  "ItemsPath": "$.items",
  "Iterator": {
    "StartAt": "YourTaskState",
    "States": {
      "YourTaskState": {
        "Type": "Task",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:function:FUNCTION_NAME",
        "End": true
      }
    }
  },
  "End": true
}

if this didn't work out also, feel free to share some code snippet to check it

You are correct. It looks like the item processor is the replacement for the iterator so to move over would be to go backwards. I think I’ll find another way forward. Thank you for the assist.
